# Track Print Button Clicked or not of chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I want to update database only if Print button clicked of Print dialogue of chrome browser. i want to track only Print button not cancel.

Help Me..

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `matchMedia` method, in javascript, wherein you attach a listener to check for the `print` media query to determine when something was printed. There is a write-up about its usage for this exact purpose, here: [Use matchMedia to detect when printing from a browser.](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2012/06/15/detecting-print-requests-with-javascript/)

An excerpt:

```
var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
mediaQueryList.addListener(function(mql) {
    if (mql.matches) {
        console.log('onbeforeprint equivalent');
    } else {
        console.log('onafterprint equivalent');
    }
});
```

You can also read the specs on  [window.matchMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) to learn more.